# Подсчёт количества элементов ассоциативного массива с определённым значением

Tags: php

Есть ли какая-то функция или способ подсчитать количество ключей в ассоциативном массиве, значения которых равны определённому числу? В частности, мне требуется подсчитать количество ключей, в которых значение равно 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Требуется подсчитать количество ключей, в которых значение равно 1*

Можно подсчитать с помощью [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-count-values.php):

```
$need = 1;

$array = [1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello"];
$all = array_count_values($array);

echo $all[$need];
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php

```
$count = array_reduce($myArray, function($sum, $item) {
    if($item === 1) {
        $sum++;
    }
}, 0);
```